# Databound DataGridView Cell Format Int to Month Name Conversion

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, formatting, int

I have a databound datagridview. In it I have a column that has NULL values and 1-12. How can I at runtime make the datagridview turn the 1 into January and display it in the cell? And the NULL into another pre-defined string?

I tried looking at the cell format, changed it to custom, then put in "MMM" but it did not work and displayed "MMM" in the actual cell.

Please help.

EDIT: Its winforms c#4.0, the field is bound to Int field from an entity in EF. And no need for culture sensitive, english is fine.

EDIT: I tried {0:MMM} it didnt work, just displayed {X:MMM} in cell where X is int.

Some screenshots:

[image: format]

[image: result]

Comment: Do you need this to be multilingual/culture sensitive? Plus is this currently bound to an 'int?' type?

Comment: Is this win forms? or ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way of going about this is to **create a separate property for databinding**, such as `DisplayMonth` which contains the logic you want, then bind the cell to that property instead.  Are you using EF-generated classes?  If so, you can add this property to a partial class to extend the one generated by EF.

It would look something like:

```
public string DisplayMonth
{
  get { return ConvertToString(this.Date); //TODO: create ConvertToString method }
  set { return this.Date = ConvertFromString() //TODO: create ConvertFromString method ; }
}
```

As mentioned already, you can also use the `CellFormatting` event, however you'll need to re-implement it everywhere this object is used in a grid.

Answer (score 4):

If WinForms try this:

Use [Column.DefaultCellStyle.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format.aspx) property or set it in [designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95y5fz2x.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.CELLSTYLEDIALOG%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true).

This post should clarify any doubt:

[Customize format of DateTime string in WPF and WinForm data binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2009/07/07/customize-format-of-datetime-string-in-wpf-and-winform-data-binding.aspx)

---

**PROBLEM**: string formatting masks will only work with DateTime values. You have int and in this case I think you'll have to write a converter function...

Check this:

[DataGridView.CellFormatting Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx)

Comment: Yes I tried setting it to {0:MMM} in the Format property in designer, it just displayed {X:MMM} in every cell, where X = int.

Comment: I know about the Cell Formatting event, I was hoping for a simpler way as I have to display this in many grids. But I guess I don't have an option. Also I was thinking my own formatting would be less efficient than built in formatting by the grid itself.

Comment: Can't you return a DateTime value in this column? It'd be really simple if that was possible... :) This way you can use the format mask as expected showing only the month name.

Comment: This field is called MOT Month. Unfortunately it has to cover an entire month, currently it is like "January" in the table, I thought it would be more efficient to store 1 instead and convert at runtime, with the added advantage that I could do some maths on it. A date time would take more space in DB, and its something undesirable.